# How to update a column in mysql from other 2 columns in the same table

Tags: mysql

I want to get data from 2 columns, from '1h' and 'rate', and combine these values with '|' and add it to another column named '24h'. Something like "1h|rate"

```
update `exchanges` set 24h = `1h`.'|'.`rate` where id=1
```

Comment: not sure why you are doing this instead of doing this i advice you to use [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) instead or use a VIEW or normal SELECT to generate a concat when you need it which make more sense..

Comment: this is only needed one time, so no big deal. will not use this continuously

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
update `exchanges` 
set `24h` = concat(`1h`, '|', `rate`) 
where id = 1
```

But note that this seems to be a denormalized column if you put multiple values in it.